# Pandas - Math Diffs Between Two DataFrames when Index Exists in only one DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a report based on a single dataframe that shows the mathematical differences between the data.

Single Data Frame:
[image: single df]

Differences Report
[image: diff report]

I split the data into two dataframes using the EvaluatePoint column and then create a Differences Report DataFrame using the End of Day Dataframe

```
endofday_df = df[df.EvaluatePoint == 'EndOfDay']
intraday_df = df[df.EvaluatePoint == 'IntraDay']
report_df = endofday_df[['EvaluateDate', 'InvoiceNumber', 'InvoiceItem']]
```

I set the index on all 3 to EvaluateDate, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceItem

```
endofday_df = endofday_df.set_index(['EvaluateDate', 'InvoiceNumber', 'InvoiceItem'])
intraday_df = endofday_df.set_index(['EvaluateDate', 'InvoiceNumber', 'InvoiceItem'])
report_df = endofday_df.set_index(['EvaluateDate', 'InvoiceNumber', 'InvoiceItem'])
```

From here I can create the Additional Differences Columns

```
report_df['CostDiff'] = endofday_df['Cost'] - intraday_df['Cost']
```

This works for the most part except for the cases where the index (EvaluateDate, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceItem) only exists in either endofday_df or intraday_df.

1. Is this the best method to create the Report?
2. How can I include the cases where the index does not exist in both data frames when I am subtracting the data? Should I create an additional two dataframes where the index only exists in one?

Thanks,

**EDIT**

Adding the full code below. Hopefully this makes it a bit more clear as to what I'm doing and trying to get to.

Issues are:

1. endofday_df - Invoice number 123699 doesn't exist in intraday_df so these return NaN for differences
2. intraday_df - Invoice number 123696 doesn't exist in endofday_df so it does not show up in report_df

My thoughts are after creating endofday_df and intraday_df create 4 more dataframes

1. endofday_common_df / intraday_common_df - These would only contain the indexes ('EvaluateDate', 'InvoiceNumber', 'InvoiceItem') that are common to both DataFrames. This way any mathematical operations work properly
2. endofday_only_df / intraday_only_df - These would only contain the indexes that are in endofday only and intraday only

A bit stuck on how to accomplish this, open to suggestions on better ways of doing this as well

```
import pandas as pd

Invoices = {'EvaluatePoint': ['EndOfDay', 'EndOfDay', 'EndOfDay', 'EndOfDay', 'EndOfDay', 'EndOfDay', 'IntraDay', 'IntraDay', 'IntraDay', 'IntraDay', 'IntraDay'],
            'EvaluateDate':  ['08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021'],
            'InvoiceNumber': [123697, 123697, 123697, 123698, 123699, 123699, 123696, 123697, 123697, 123697, 123698],
            'InvoiceItem': [0,1,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0],
            'Cost': [-3569,-3745,-3921,-4097,-4273,-4449,-4625,-3569,-3745,-4678,-5329],
            'Proceeds': [7000,7569,8138,8707,9276,9845,10414,7000,7569,8138,12690],
            'NetAmount': [3431,3824,4217,4610,5003,5396,5789,3431,3824,3460,7361]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(Invoices, columns = ['EvaluatePoint', 'EvaluateDate','InvoiceNumber','InvoiceItem','Cost','Proceeds','NetAmount'])
#print(df)

endofday_df = df[df.EvaluatePoint == 'EndOfDay']
intraday_df = df[df.EvaluatePoint == 'IntraDay']
#print(endofday_df)
#print(intraday_df)

#create base output report from endofday_df
report_df = endofday_df[['EvaluateDate','InvoiceNumber','InvoiceItem']]
#print(report_df)

df_index = ['EvaluateDate','InvoiceNumber','InvoiceItem']

endofday_df = endofday_df.set_index(df_index)
intraday_df = intraday_df.set_index(df_index)
report_df = report_df.set_index(df_index)

DiffColumns = ['Cost','Proceeds','NetAmount']

for col in DiffColumns:
    report_df['DiffOf' + str(col)] = endofday_df[col] - intraday_df[col]

print(report_df)
report_df.to_csv("DiffReport.csv",index=True, header=True)
```

Comment: You need to tell us, how would you resolve such a situation (the logic to use) for anyone to suggest a solution.

Comment: Well I would still show the difference. If it existed during end of day difference would be equal to the cost, if during intra day would be negative the cost.

I am really looking for how I should move the indexes that only exist either in endofday or intraday to their own dataframe...

Comment: That doesn't say anything about how to align the different rows.  When you do `df1['Cost'] - df2['Cost']`, the two arrays are aligned based on the index.  If those 3 index columns (eval date, invoice number, and item) do not exist, then the earlier `.set_index()` doesn't work, so there needs to be an alternative way to do the alignment.  You are expecting things to work magically.

Comment: Yes that I why I am trying to compare the two dataframes (endofday_df & intraday_df) and remove the rows where the index that does not exist in the other data frame to their own dataframes (lets call them endofday_only_df and intraday_only_df)

Just not exactly sure how to accomplish that.

Comment: See my suggested answer.  You need to edit your question to clarify this point. As worded currently, this is not clear from the question.  If my suggestion doesn't help, please try to give details in the edited question why it doesn't help.  Please also include example data so that people can test things.

Comment: thank you, I've added more details to the original post, hopefully this is more clear.

Comment: Okay, much clearer now, confirms what I had gleaned from the comments.  Doesn't my current answer give you a path forward?  BTW, it should be 3 dataframes, These two: `endofday_common_df`, `intraday_common_df` have the same set of rows.

Comment: Check my revised answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, was having issues getting it to work comepletely. With a bit more searching I ended up using intersection() and difference() instead to split up the indexes. Final code is below.

I also tried to use for loops on reset_index and set_index but it would not stay outside the for loop, what should I do here to fix that?

```
DF_Set_Index_List = [report_same_df, report_eod_df, report_intra_df, endofday_same_df, intraday_same_df, endofday_only_df, intraday_only_df]
for df_sil in DF_Set_Index_List:
    print(df_sil,'\n\n\n')
    df_sil = df_sil.set_index(df_default_index)
    print('INDEX: \n', df_sil.index)

print('\n\n', 'Outside Loop')
print(report_same_df)
print('\n\n')
print(report_same_df.index)
```

Any feedback on the final code below, cleanups, more efficient methods...etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pandas as pd
from sys import exit

Invoices = {'EvaluatePoint': ['EndOfDay', 'EndOfDay', 'EndOfDay', 'EndOfDay', 'EndOfDay', 'EndOfDay', 'IntraDay', 'IntraDay', 'IntraDay', 'IntraDay', 'IntraDay'],
            'EvaluateDate':  ['08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021','08/06/2021'],
            'InvoiceNumber': [123697, 123697, 123697, 123698, 123699, 123699, 123696, 123697, 123697, 123697, 123698],
            'InvoiceItem': [0,1,2,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0],
            'Cost': [-3569,-3745,-3921,-4097,-4273,-4449,-4625,-3569,-3745,-4678,-5329],
            'Proceeds': [7000,7569,8138,8707,9276,9845,10414,7000,7569,8138,12690],
            'NetAmount': [3431,3824,4217,4610,5003,5396,5789,3431,3824,3460,7361]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(Invoices, columns = ['EvaluatePoint', 'EvaluateDate','InvoiceNumber','InvoiceItem','Cost','Proceeds','NetAmount'])

endofday_df = df[df.EvaluatePoint == 'EndOfDay']
intraday_df = df[df.EvaluatePoint == 'IntraDay']

# Set Default Index to compare DataFrames
df_default_index = ['EvaluateDate','InvoiceNumber','InvoiceItem']
endofday_df = endofday_df.set_index(df_default_index)
intraday_df = intraday_df.set_index(df_default_index)

# Create var where index exists in both EndOfDay and IntraDay
idx_same = endofday_df.index.intersection(intraday_df.index)
# Create var where index exists only in EndOfDay or IntraDay
idx_eod_only = endofday_df.index.difference(intraday_df.index)
idx_intra_only = intraday_df.index.difference(endofday_df.index)

#create DataFrames where index is the same between EndOfDay and IntraDay
endofday_same_df = endofday_df.loc[idx_same]
intraday_same_df = intraday_df.loc[idx_same]
#create DataFrames where index is the only in EndOfDay or IntraDay
endofday_only_df = endofday_df.loc[idx_eod_only]
intraday_only_df = intraday_df.loc[idx_intra_only]

# Reset Index so we have only raw data
endofday_same_df = endofday_same_df.reset_index()
intraday_same_df = intraday_same_df.reset_index()
endofday_only_df = endofday_only_df.reset_index()
intraday_only_df = intraday_only_df.reset_index()

# Create Base Report
report_same_df = endofday_same_df[['EvaluateDate','InvoiceNumber','InvoiceItem']]
report_eod_df = endofday_only_df[['EvaluateDate','InvoiceNumber','InvoiceItem']]
report_intra_df = intraday_only_df[['EvaluateDate','InvoiceNumber','InvoiceItem']]

report_same_df = report_same_df.set_index(df_default_index)
report_eod_df = report_eod_df.set_index(df_default_index)
report_intra_df = report_intra_df.set_index(df_default_index)
endofday_same_df = endofday_same_df.set_index(df_default_index)
intraday_same_df = intraday_same_df.set_index(df_default_index)
endofday_only_df = endofday_only_df.set_index(df_default_index)
intraday_only_df = intraday_only_df.set_index(df_default_index)

DiffColumns = ['Cost','Proceeds','NetAmount']
for col in DiffColumns:
    report_same_df['DiffOf' + str(col)] = endofday_same_df[col] - intraday_same_df[col]
    report_eod_df['DiffOf' + str(col)] = endofday_only_df[col]
    report_intra_df['DiffOf' + str(col)] = -intraday_only_df[col]

report_df = pd.concat([report_same_df, report_eod_df, report_intra_df])
print(report_df)
report_df.to_csv("DiffReport.csv", index=True, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

3 dataframes should be fine for your case.  These 2 have the same rows: `endofday_common_df`, `intraday_common_df`.

You can separate the 3 sets of rows by doing the alignment step separately:

```
eod, intrad = endofday_df.align(intraday_df)
```

Get the common rows, just pick any column with numbers, doesn't matter which, here I chose "Cost":

```
common = (~eod["Cost"].isna()) & (~intrad["Cost"].isna())
```

Then the report with common rows is:

```
DiffColumns = ["Cost", "Proceeds", "NetAmount"]
report_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {f"DiffOf{col}": eod[common][col] - intrad[common][col] for col in DiffColumns}
)
```

For your given data, it looks like this:

```
                                        DiffOfCost  DiffOfProceeds  DiffOfNetAmount
EvaluateDate InvoiceNumber InvoiceItem                                             
08/06/2021   123697        0                   0.0             0.0              0.0
                           1                   0.0             0.0              0.0
                           2                 757.0             0.0            757.0
             123698        0                1232.0         -3983.0          -2751.0
```

EOD only rows are (again, choose a numeric column):

```
only_in_eod = (~eod["Cost"].isna()) & (intrad["Cost"].isna())
print(eod[only_in_eod])
```

Which looks like this:

```
                                       EvaluatePoint    Cost  Proceeds  NetAmount
EvaluateDate InvoiceNumber InvoiceItem                                           
08/06/2021   123699        0                EndOfDay -4273.0    9276.0     5003.0
                           1                EndOfDay -4449.0    9845.0     5396.0
```

And intra day only rows are:

```
only_in_intrad = (eod["Cost"].isna()) & (~intrad["Cost"].isna())
print(intrad[only_in_intrad])
```

Which looks like:

```
                                       EvaluatePoint    Cost  Proceeds  NetAmount
EvaluateDate InvoiceNumber InvoiceItem                                           
08/06/2021   123696        0                IntraDay -4625.0   10414.0     5789.0
```